# Convexifying products and quotients

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I would like to ask about convexity of the product of two continuous decision variables. Would it be possible to convexify it?

What about the case where two continuous variables are divided? Would the treatment be equivalent to the product of two variables where the denominator will have a negative power?

Comment: Please provide background and motivation.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the context is that you wish to solve an optimization problem involving such a product (or quotient) using a convex optimization solver, perhaps called by a convex optimization modeling tool, such as CVX.

As you perhaps know, the product of tow continuous variables has a Hessian which is indefinite. Therefore, the product is neither convex nor concave.

The product of two continuous variables is MILP (Mixed Integer Linear Program) representable, providing that there are finite lower and upper bounds on both variables, and requiring discretization (limited number of binary "decimal" places) for one of the variables. This is accomplished using binary expansion for one of the  variables. Then model all binary, continuous product terms per FICO MIP formulations and linearizations https://www.artelys.com/uploads/pdfs/Xpress/mipformref-1.pdf section 2.8. I leave the slightly messy details to you. However, I absolutely do not recommend doing this. Rather, use a non-convex optimization solver.

The simplest way to convexify such a product, which is a bilinear function, is to fix one variable (at a time). Then the product is convex (actually linear) in the other variable. You could then formulate a convex optimization problem, starting with some initial value for the variable which is fixed, and finding the optimal solution of that problem (which is convex if the rest of the model is). Then fix the just optimized variables at its optimal value and optimize with respect to the other variables. Iterate until convergence. However, such an alternating minimization scheme is not guaranteed to converge to anything, let alone a local minimum of the original problem, let alone a global minimum of the original problem.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your clear reply and your suggestions.
From what I have understood, the case would have been easier if one the variables is an integer. I thought that dealing with continuous variables would be easier.

Comment: If one of the variables were an integer, you could represent that variable by a binary expansion, then employ the suggestion. Keep in mind that a MILP is a non-convex problem, which might be difficult to solve if there are very many integer (binary) variables. The greater the magnitude bounds on the integer variable, the greater the number of binary variables need to be introduced for the binary expansion, and the corresponding greater the number of binary, continuous product terms which need to be linearzed by Big M.

Comment: If both variables are continuous, you will need additional binary variables for the discretized binary expansion, depending on the number of digits to be used in the discretization. Yes it can be modeled. But I wouldn't do it. And actually, the problem you have to solve may not be a MILP, but would be a Mixed Integer (Binary) Convex Program, if the rest of the problem were not linear.  For instance, if otherwise an SOCP, employing the binary expansion would result in an MISOCP.

Comment: Would McCormick envelopes be useful for this case?

Comment: McCormick envelopes can be used to derive a convex relaxation. This can be used as part of a global optimization algorithm in order to get a lower bound (if minimizing) on the optimal objective value of the original problem. I continue to advice, as i did in my answer, to  use a non-convex optimization solver, which can be either a  local or global optimization solver. You will have a hard time duplicating the efficiency and robustness of top echelon nonlinear non-convex solvers if you try to implement your own algorithm.